# Finding Kubernetes search terms

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have problems finding the values used for selecting or displaying objects in kubernetes. I feel like I'm not using the kubernetes docs correctly or these are linked with a command I haven't learned yet.

Examples:

1. Find all the pods on a certain node? How do you know it's in spec.nodeName

   `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide --field-selector spec.nodeName=<node>`
2. Get all Pods in a running state? How do you know this value is stored in status.phase

   `kubectl get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running`
3. Get all pods but only listing the name, How do you know it called metadata.name

   `kubectl get pods -o custom-columns:POD:metadata.name`

Comment: If it's hard to keep up with K8s commands, then use `grep` (or for your third case, combine it with `sed`) to solve all these use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Each resource in Kubernetes is described by some specification. You can find the detailed  spec for the resources in the documentation, for example here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/. If you navigate to the `Pod` definition (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#pod-v1-core) you will see all the properties of the `Pod` type with their underlying types.

For example, your first point, reading the `PodSpec` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#podspec-v1-core) you can see that the `nodeName` property holds the name of a node that should be used to schedule the pod.

Same documentation can be reviewed from the `kubectl` command. To get the documentation for `PodSpec` you can just type `kubectl explain pod.spec`

Comment: For anyone else having this problem the best way is using the advice in @krisas comment. I typically use the `kubectl explain pod` to get the different fields like metadata,spec,status,etc. then use `kubectl explain pod.metadata | grep name` to find the sub field.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the documentation of kubectl command line to understand how to user it. The below link give you exactly the same.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/

Meanwhile the third command should be modified as below to get the output as the only the name of the pod.

```
kubectl get pods  --output=custom-columns=NAME:metadata.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the description of almost any Kubernetes object in the [API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/).
Specifically, the `pod` object attributes are described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#pod-v1-core).

Each member of the pod object can be further explored via the direct links found in the same documentation page.

`--field-selector` allows you to create any filter you need as you already very well described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Practical answers:

> Find all the pods on a certain node?

It's included in the output of

```
kubectl describe node node-001.example.com
```

> Get all Pods in a running state?

```
kubectl get pods | grep Running
```

> Get all pods but only listing the name

```
kubectl get pods -o name
```

Note that these particular commands don't combine especially well.  If you want to get the name only of all of the running pods on a specific node, you can combine the more detailed options in the original question (as others have suggested, using the [Pod definition in the API docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#pod-v1-core) as a reference).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @krizas answer wanna add you can also use `--recurcive` option of `kubectl explain` output

> Add the --recursive flag to display all of the fields at once without
> descriptions. Information about each field is retrieved from the
> server in OpenAPI format.

What I mean is that you can have short list of all available objects and sub-objects and only then  have their descriptions. E.g

```
 kubectl explain pod --recursive
 #will give you all sub-objects of pod
```

Or you can have all pod.metadata objects like

```
kubectl explain pod.metadata --recursive
FIELDS:
   annotations  <map[string]string>
   clusterName  <string>
   creationTimestamp    <string>
   deletionGracePeriodSeconds   <integer>
   deletionTimestamp    <string>
   finalizers   <[]string>
   generateName <string>
   generation   <integer>
   initializers <Object>
      pending   <[]Object>
         name   <string>
      result    <Object>
         apiVersion     <string>
         code   <integer>
         details        <Object>
            causes      <[]Object>
               field    <string>
               message  <string>
               reason   <string>
            group       <string>
            kind        <string>
            name        <string>
            retryAfterSeconds   <integer>
            uid <string>
         kind   <string>
         message        <string>
         metadata       <Object>
            continue    <string>
            resourceVersion     <string>
            selfLink    <string>
         reason <string>
         status <string>
   labels       <map[string]string>
   managedFields        <[]Object>
      apiVersion        <string>
      fields    <map[string]>
      manager   <string>
      operation <string>
      time      <string>
   name <string>
   namespace    <string>
   ownerReferences      <[]Object>
      apiVersion        <string>
      blockOwnerDeletion        <boolean>
      controller        <boolean>
      kind      <string>
      name      <string>
      uid       <string>
   resourceVersion      <string>
   selfLink     <string>
   uid  <string>
```

Then its easy to explain exact object you need. Plus you have  good structure in front of your eyes.